# create a record set to a spot instance on aws route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is it possible to create a recordset to a spot instance using route 53?

I've created a fleet spot request and I want to be able to create an A name in route53 without using elastic IP.

Is that feature possible? because I know that when the instance will go down a new IP will be assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

1. You can configure the `UserData` option of the  `Launch Template` for your Spot instances to register themselves to Route53, every time they are launched. An instance can get its assigned public IP by checking the following endpoint: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`. For this to work, you need to add Route53 write permissions to the EC2 instance. [Here is the `Launch Template` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html)
2. Use `Cloudwatch Events` and `Lambda` to update the DNS records when an EC2 instance changes its state. You can configure `CloudWatch` to receive changes to EC2 state changes, and trigger a `Lambda` function that reacts to them. For example, when an instance gets terminated you can remove them from the recordset, and add a new one when it goes from `pending` to `running`. [Check this AWS Blog Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-dynamic-dns-for-route-53-using-cloudwatch-events-and-lambda/) for more information on how to do this.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Spot fleet and Spot requests both can use [Launch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html). In the launch template you can assign the spot instances roles that can allow you to modify the Route 53 zones.
In the template use the user data feature to write a script that executes during the startup of the Instance. 
This script can get the IP address of the instances.

Example: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`  for private IP address or `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` for public IP address.

And this IP address then can be updated in the A record using [AWS Cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's different with fleets but I was having a similar problem with test servers and persistent spot requests. We used some scripting, cron jobs on reboot and the AWS CLI that [Yogesh_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1747018/yogesh-d) referenced above. I'm not sure this would work for your case but here's the post just in case: [Is there a way to have an AWS spot instance register with route53 on boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217495/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-aws-spot-instance-register-with-route53-on-boot/72217496#72217496)